# How to get a specific tag of xml from array output in soap response?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, bpel

I'am working on WS project of composing two web services ..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:CustomerOperationResponse xmlns:m="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/GetTopSong/src/Customer">
<TopSong xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item xsi:type="tns:TopSong">
      <rank xsi:type="xsd:int">1</rank>
      <artist xsi:type="xsd:string">Katy Perry</artist>
      <song xsi:type="xsd:string">Dark Horse (feat. Juicy J)</song>
      <image xsi:type="xsd:string">http://a252.phobos.apple.com/us</image>
      <itunes xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
      <url xsi:type="xsd:string"> </url>
    </item>
</TopSong>
```

i need to take only Rank and Song from the above soap response to be consumed by the second web service. any clue on how to omit the rest tags [artist, image,..]  ?

P.S: Topsong is a part name which i created as a result. the 'item' is an array name from the server encapsulating the tags inside. i need only 2 of them.

Comment: complete your question pls. how's your second webservice consuming this soap response?

Comment: the input parameters of the second web service are ONLY 'rank' and 'song'. so i need to parse this soap response of the primary service to feed the second service. but since the second service doesn't take the rest outputs i don't need them to come as response.

Comment: Ok, so basically u want to parse this soap response and get only those two fields. That means you must have been written a client code to call these webservices and to get above response, if client is written in java i can provide you DOM parser code to parse above response as per your requirement.

Comment: i appreciate your suggestion and cooperation but i use 'Do Marshal' [Extension function of BPEL assignments]. it helps me to get marshaled String representation of the soap response. in addition i put substring after and before to extract the needed node elements. boooom